# sql update many rows based on value in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a really inefficient sql script that takes the following table, and populates val2 using a cursor.  I want to be able to update all of the val2 values with a single update, but val2 is calculated using val1 for each row.

```
val1: 1, val2 0
val1: 2, val2 0 
val1: 3, val2 0
val1: 4, val2 0
val1: 5, val2 0
```

So I imagine, you'd have something like this:

```
UPDATE Table SET val2 = (some code based on val1 for each row)
```

How can I write this into a single line of sql?

Comment: I've given you my best guess, but you'll need to be more specific about the code you want if you want a more complete answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update table set val2 = val1 + 1
```

Works just like that! If you have some set of codes that you want to have applied by a `case` statement:

```
update table set
    val2 = 
        case 
            when val1 = 1 then 'One'
            when val1 = 2 then 'Two'
            when val1 = 3 then 'Three'
            else 'Something something'
        end
```

Comment: I see, so if you just use val1 in the set val2 statement, it will assume it is the val1 in the same row.  Thanks :)

Comment: @sooprise - yes, in much the same way as you can combine values from multiple columns in a select statement